# Backstrech not able to display slide show nor any image

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullscreen, jquery-backstretch

I am trying to show full size background image for that i am using this [jquery plugin](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch)
I am following this [example](http://www.bluenotesentertainment.com/siteelements/iweb-demos/backstretch/)

my code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>full page image</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            < script >
                    $.backstretch([
                        "http://media1.santabanta.com/full5/Indian%20%20Celebrities(F)/Gehana%20Vasisth/gehana-vasisth-0a.jpg",
                        "http://media1.santabanta.com/full5/Indian%20%20Celebrities(F)/Disha%20Pandey/disha-pandey-1a.jpg",
                        "E:\wall\beaches-82a.jpg"
                    ], {
                        fade: 750,
                        duration: 4000
                    });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is the problem with above code. how to make it working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of the path to your files are correct by checking the browser console or network tab.

Also, you need to remove `<script>` tag under `<script type="text/javascript">` because you cannot have nested `<script>` tags. Then it should work as expected.

Comment: Yes removed `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: It is showing not found `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) ` dome.jpg. I have not incuded this in my images

Comment: You need to remove `< script >`. Did you do it?

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < test.jsp:13
GET http://localhost:8084/sms/pages/dome.jpg 404 (Not Found) `